# multiple controls in UIView using IB

Tags: iphone

How can I create multiple controls (such as UISwitch) in a UIView (or on top of UIScrollView) using the interface builder? I have about 20 such controls.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can drag-n-drop as many controls as you want into a view from the library panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the right corner bottom in the uiintrface builder you can drag it and make the view bigger as per your requirement then add scroll bar in the view and then add all your 20 controllers on that scroll bar...

Comment: adding here means dragging the control from library and dropping it onto your view. Thanks